# How would I prove a logical expression containing contrapositives and equivalencies with a truth table?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

How would you construct the truth table for ~P => (Q<=>R) ?

So I know how to start writing a truth table starting a P column, Q column, P => Q column, etc...I get confused when we're talking about contrapositives as in the case of P and then with Q and R being equivalent to each other...

Would I treat this the same way I would with ~P => Q because Q and R are equivalent?

Comment: What do you mean, "prove" this statement?  If you mean prove it is always true, you can't because it isn't.  Please clarify.

Comment: @David I would like to write the truth table for this expression. Therefore, I can see how it isn't always true.

Comment: It is a "usual" truth table for a formula with 3 prop letters : $2^3$ rows. Then you have to "eveluate" every single row according to the tables for the connectives, starting from the "inner" part (see the parentheses : $(Q \Leftrightarrow R)$).

Comment: In all the rows with $Q$ TRUE and $R$ FALSE, or $Q$ FALSE and $R$ TRUE, of course $(Q \Leftrightarrow R)$ will be eveluated to FALSE. The corresponding rows where $P$ is FALSE will produce as a final result : FALSE.

Comment: Brackets means evaluate the inner expression first. Don't attempt to use any prior notion of "equivalence" or "contrapositive". Just use the truth tables for each individual boolean operation, one by one in the order needed. And negation is performed first before implication.